# Spotlight searches in Mail.app's Smart folders

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail, spotlight

Is there a way to use the Spotlight syntax in Mail.app's Smart Folders? I'd like to make advanced boolean searches.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that this is already in Mail.app.
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071121105941992

This might also do the trick.
http://tech.kateva.org/2009/01/enabling-spotlight-search-of-os-x.html